# How to define a variable being a dictionary with list values in Robot Framework

Tags: python, dictionary, robotframework

In one of my testcases I need to define a dictionary, where the keys are string and the values are arrays of strings. How can I do so in Robot Framework?

My first try using a construct as shown below, will not work.

```
*** Variables ***
&{Dictionary}     A=StringA1  StringA2   
...               B=StringB1   StringB2
```

Another idea might be to use Evaluate and pass the python expression for a dictionary, but is this the only way how it can done?

```
*** Variables ***
&{Dictionary}     Evaluate  { "A" : ["StringA1",  "StringA2"], "B": ["StringB1","StringB2"]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple more options beside using the `Evaluate` keyword.

1. You could use a Python variable file:

   ```
   DICTIONARY = { "A" : ["StringA1",  "StringA2"], "B": ["StringB1","StringB2"]}
   ```

   Suite:

   ```
   *** Settings ***
   Variables    VariableFile.py

   *** Test Cases ***
   Test
       Log    ${DICTIONARY}
   ```
2. You can define your lists separately, and then pass them as scalar variables when defining the dictionary.

   ```
   *** Variables ***
   @{list1}    StringA1    StringA2
   @{list2}    StringB1    StringB1
   &{Dictionary}    A=${list1}    B=${list2}

   *** Test Cases ***
   Test
       Log    ${Dictionary}
   ```
3. You can create a user keyword using the `Create List` and `Create Dictionary` keywords. You can achieve the same in Python by writing a small library.

   ```
   *** Test Cases ***
   Test
       ${Dictionary}=    Create Dict With List Elements
       Log    ${Dictionary}


   *** Keyword ***
   Create Dict With List Elements
       ${list1}=    Create List    StringA1    StringA2
       ${list2}=    Create List    StringB1    StringB1
       ${Dictionary}=    Create Dictionary    A=${list1}    B=${list2}
       [return]    ${Dictionary}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To add another option to [Bence Kaulics answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64022203/16694828), you can also use [Inline Python evaluation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.2.2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#inline-python-evaluation). So for example:

```
&{Dictionary}    A=${{["StringA1","StringA2"]}}    B=${{["StringB1","StringB2"]}}
```