# Can I declare a list inside a dictionary in Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, testing, robotframework

Im new to robot framework

Could anyones help with this concern.

In python we can declare a dictionary that contain a list

```
dict = {"key1":[1,2,3,4,5], "key2":3, "key3":"string"}
```

I wonder if we can do the same thing in robot framework?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a variable being a dictionary with list values in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64021715/how-to-define-a-variable-being-a-dictionary-with-list-values-in-robot-framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via the [Create List](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Create%20List) and [Create Dictionary](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Create%20Dictionary) keywords:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example 1
    ${key1}  Create list   ${1}  ${2}  ${3}  ${4}  ${5}   # coerce values to integers
    ${key2}  Set variable  ${3}  # coerce to integer
    ${key3}  Set variable  string
    ${dict}=  Create dictionary
    ...  key1=${key1}
    ...  key2=${key2}
    ...  key3=${key3}
```

Starting with robot framework 3.2 you can use [inline evaluation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#inline-python-evaluation) by putting a python expression between `${{` and `}}`. For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example 2
    ${dict}=  Set variable  ${{ {"key1":[1,2,3,4,5], "key2":3, "key3":"string"} }}
```

The nice thing about inline evaluation is that you can use it in the variables section:

```
*** Variables ***
${dict}   ${{ {"key1":[1,2,3,4,5], "key2":3, "key3":"string"} }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So if I want to  call the key1. can I use the syntax ${dict.key1} ?

Comment: @PaulTran: no, that's not correct dict syntax. It should be `${dict['key1']}`.